# git recover commit netbeans

Tags: java, git, github, netbeans

1. I've made a lot of code changes. IDE Netbeans
2. I had a lot of highlighted files.
3. (I'm new to github) then I did this:
   [image]
4. And my whole story is gone:
   [image]

I learned that disappeared "commits":

[image]

But how now to recover them I don't know

Comment: I really dont understand the question here? Can you provide more information? You have pulled from _origin/master_ and then committed your local changes, do you want to know how to remove a commit that you have just made? What do you mean with _"recover"_ here.

Comment: I wrote code. There are new commits. Then My Project -> Git -> Remote -> Pull. And all my old commits are erased. Question how do I restore them ?

Comment: If you have local changes and or commits not pushed to the remote and execute _git pull_ you will be forced to merge those changes. Git will not override your changes, unless you tell it to do so. Are you sure that your changes are lost? If you did commit your changes, run _git status_ to see the number of outgoing commits.

Comment: Git didn't save my changes. Also NetBeans nothing saved in the history file. Maybe it's a glitch.

Comment: Please list the output of the _git status_ command or provide more information, otherwise i wont be able to locate the issue. I dont think that the error is caused by git itself.

Comment: Thank you for listening. The problem was NetBeans. I had to reboot. And restore code through history in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvKR.png)
2. reboot NetBeans
3. [recover the code through NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRK1j.png)